# Capture Traces from AWS Lambda to Step Function to Lambda

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-step-functions, aws-xray

I am experimenting with Lambdas and I am having a hard time passing traces from a Lambda to a Step Function which has a lambda within it.

So structure looks something like this:

Lambda Code call step function -> Step function -> Lambda.

Problem is that I am getting two different traces, instead of the desired one trace,
which effectively captures lambda -> step function -> lambda all under one trace id.

1st trace - Lambda A
2nd trace - Step Function ->  Lambda B

Is this possible to unify the traces, so it looks like this?

Trace 3 - Lambda A -> Step Function -> Lambda B (TraceId: 1) ~ Something like that

And if so how would I go about doing that.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you passing the trace header with value of Lambda A trace ID when invoking the State Machine? See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/apireference/API_StartExecution.html

> traceHeader
> Passes the AWS X-Ray trace header. The trace header can also be passed in the request payload.

Comment: Yes I am, and I have enabled tracing on step function but the graphs still arent connected. Am I supposed to use "Active" for tracing mode for both lambdas? 

Tracing is enabled for all of our resources right now.

Comment: AFAIK active tracing is not required and having it enabled it okay too. Can you also share how the traceHeader value content looks like?

Comment: You should be also able to use X-ray client in your code that can propagate trace headers automatically, example for .net https://docs.aws.amazon.com/xray/latest/devguide/xray-sdk-dotnet-sdkclients.html, nodejs https://docs.aws.amazon.com/xray/latest/devguide/xray-sdk-nodejs-awssdkclients.html